# Energy paradox in Capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, potential, capacitance

Consider a sphere $S_1$ radius a and another concentric hollow sphere $S_2$ of radius b and small thickness t. Let us charge the inner sphere by some amount q. As a result -q charge shall appear on the inner surface of $S_2$ and +q on it's outer surface. Now let's connect the outer surface of $S_2$ to the inner sphere of another capacitor with the same setup (ie. two concentric spheres but no charge initially on either of them). Clearly there is a potential difference Between the outer surface of $S_2$ and the surface of that inner sphere,$S_3$ of the second capacitor.  So we should have +q charge going from $S_2$ to  the $S_3$. This in turn  should create same kind of charge distribution in THAT capacitor's outer sphere. And we can keep going on like this as long as we want. So eventually when we separate the capacitors, we will have infinity many charged capacitors.

So, where is my reasoning wrong? Is there some reason why charge should not flow from $S_2$ to $S_3$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to say that $0<a<b$. Let you initially put $+Q$ on $S_1$, so that the inner surface of $S_2$ has $-Q$ and the outer surface of $S_2$ has $+Q$ as you described.

When you connect $S_2$ with $S_3$, an amount of charge $+q$, satisfying $0<|q|<|Q|$, flows from $S_2$ to $S_3$, and then $S_4$ will have inner surface charge $-q$ and outer surface charge $+q$.

Now, the effect of this manipulation is that $S_2$ has an outer surface charge $+Q-q$ satisfying $0<|Q-q|<|Q|$ and the outer surface of $S_4$ has $+q$ satisfying $0<|q|<|Q|$, i.e. as you keep doing this, the spheres get weaker and weaker charged. It will not be worth the effort after a while.

Also, you expend work doing this. It is not free.

Comment: Can you please explain why |Q|>|q|? Why is that a necessity? Why not all the charge flow from s2 to s3?

Comment: When a charged thing touches an uncharged thing, the end result is that both objects become charged to the same voltage. It is never a transfer of all the excess charge from one place to another.